# What happens when Actions & Buttons are converted automatically to Lightning?

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-actions

I'm working through automated updates using the Lightning Experience Configuration Converter tool. It was apparent what was happening with Visualforce pages, as a new attribute was added to the markup for each page. However, for the Actions & Buttons tab I'm not sure what's happening. [The docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lcc_actions_overview.htm&type=5) are decidedly vague.

When I selected some of my objects and initiated the Move option some of the objects were modified. They show *Completed* in the list. Some still show *No action required*. I'd like to know what was done with them, but it's the ones that seem stuck at *In progress* that have me most confused. I've attempted to move them several times over a course of days.

To add to the mystery, each time I scan for Actions & Buttons, or even when returning to the LECC later, the number of Actions & Buttons not updated changes on the LECC home page. Currently it reports *107 actions and buttons aren’t yet deployed*, but the number has been as low as 9 and  as high as over 350.

What does this thing do? What steps are required after an object is marked *Completed*? And what should I be doing with the ones that don't complete?

Thanks much.

Comment: any particular object those ones stuck in "in progress" are under? Or what those buttons are doing? I think the [considerations doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lcc_considerations.htm&type=5) provides more information about what can and cannot be converted. From my experience, most of these things needs to be handled manually and it simply provided suggestions. But I also didn't really dig too deep into the tool

Comment: I haven't seen any commonality between the In Progress layouts. They're on various custom objects.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Buttons will be converted to lightning components + Apex Controllers by the converter. If I remember correctly the components will be deployed to your org.

I was also interested in what's happening exactly and tracked the Conversion of a JS Button into a component over here:
https://github.com/Szandor72/lightningConverter

Not all buttons are converted the same. Salesforce tries to analyze the JS used in classic and attempts to create a component that does functionally the same.

The converter is mostly useful for those 90% of JS Buttons/Actions that are simple in nature.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but JavaScript Buttons is a different tab. We'll be doing manual conversion on many of those. That's not what we're dealing with here.

Comment: Understood. I'd like to investigate but need examples I could stick into a development org. As apparent from the answer, I focused on JS Button conversion. 
For the changes on particular objects, Search Layouts or Publisher Actions might be a reason.